# How to access Groovy nested enum in Scala?

Tags: scala, groovy

Scala has trouble accessing:

```
// Groovy
class Outer {
  enum Enum {
    VALUE
  }
}
```

What needs to be done to allow Scala to access the enum?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Java, the enum in Groovy *isn't* implicitly static. The following makes it accessible from Scala:

```
// Groovy
class Outer {
  static enum Enum {
    VALUE
  }
}
```